# rating star images are not deleted in Wordpress rating widget plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Am using rating widget plugin for star ratings of my posts in WordPress,When i delete the post from WP-admin,the title of the post got deleted but still the star ratings showing,what i have to do to delete the ratings star images?

Comment: Can you please share a URL or a screenshot.